# Calling JSON Web Service using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am calling an ASP.net application that has an exposed JSON web service interface. If I access the web service using Fiddler, everything works correctly and I get my desired result. I am trying to do the same thing using JQuery and I am running into issues. I will try to provide as much information as possible but not too much as to cloud the issue.

In Fiddler, I am using Request builder and sending a POST with the following information:

```
http://www.XXXXXXXXXX.com/TASService.svc/Logon
```

If I use Fiddler the request is sent as follows:

```
POST http://www.XXXXXXXXXX.com/TASService.svc/Logon HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json
Host: www.XXXXXXXXXX.com
Content-Length: 50

{"Email":"XXXXXXXXXX@hotmail.com","Password":"#password1"}
```

As a result I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 21:36:09 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 38
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"ContactID":52215,"Status":"Success"}
```

This is a good response (successful logon)

My HTML/JQuery is defined as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Test JSON</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.XXXXXXXXXX.com/TASService.svc/Logon",
    data: "{'Email':'XXXXXXXXXX@hotmail.com', 'Password':'#password1'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#msgid').html(msg.d);
    },
    error: function (errormessage) {
    $('#msgid').html("oops got an error!");
    }
  });
});
</script>
JSON Test Web Page
<div id="msgid">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I call run the page in FireFox I get the following (FireBug):

```
"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://www.XXXXXXXXXX.com/TASService.svc/Logon?callback=jQuery171018036323126084708_1325195152450&{%27Email%27:%27XXXXXXXXXX@hotmail.com%27,%20%27Password%27:%27#password1%27}&_=1325195152469"
```

When I view what was sent (Fiddler RAW), I get the following:

```
GET http://www.XXXXXXXXXX.com/TASService.svc/Logon?callback=jQuery171026545743770048436_1325195246881&{%27Email%27:%27XXXXXXXXXX@hotmail.com%27,%20%27Password%27:%27 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.XXXXXXXXXX.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

What I notice right away is that it is sending a GET rather than a POST, although I specified a POST on the ajax request. I believe this is why I am getting the 405 error. However, am not sure why it is doing a GET rather than a POST.

Any assistance on this will be very appreciated since time is running short on my project.

Comment: I believe you can only use GET on cross domain requests, I see you are using JSONP and doing a POST. If it's local, try to use JSON instead of JSONP

Comment: Can you try removing the double quotes around the data parameter?  It should be expecting an object, not a string (or eval the string).

Comment: @Ivan ASP.NET web services do in fact require stringified data when invoking `WebMethod`s via jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery won't send jsonp as POST: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/08/27/jquery-post-jsonp-and-cross-domain-requests/ and http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/ show why.

If you're on the same domain as the web service use `datatype: 'json'` not `datatype: 'jsonp'`